# ¿Como quitar paréntesis de la lista de categorías de woocommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Necesito ayuda para remover los paréntesis del widget de la lista de categorías de woocommerce, anteriormente lo hacia con un hook pero ahora no funciona supongo que es una actualización de woocommerce, les comparto una imagen para hacerme entender.

[image]

el hook que utilizaba antes era `woocommerce_subcategory_count_html`

Comment: ya pensaste usar `$string=str_replce(['(',')'],'',$string);` ?

Comment: @John muchas gracias por responder, digamos que la duda en si es el hook, pero reemplazar o quitar los paréntesis se como hacerlo, el hook correcto es lo que no se

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo pude solucionar, en realidad no me habia fijado que se pueden ocultar por css como siempre lo hacía por hookm, la solución es esta:

```css
.wc-block-product-categories-list-item-count:before,
.wc-block-product-categories-list-item-count:after{
    display:none;
}
```